# A dialog with multiple conditional statements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I am writing a program and I've come to a dead end.

The program starts asking:

```
button = questdlg('Would you like to train or test the network?', ...
'Artificial Neural Network', 'Train', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');
if strcmp(button,'Train') ... 

elseif strcmp(button,'Test') ...

elseif strcmp(button,'Exit') ...
```

But I want it also to ask

```
    button = questdlg('Would you like to train or test the network?', ...
    'Artificial Neural Network', 'Train', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');

    if strcmp(button,'Train') ... %do that thing 

    %but if the user wants to retrain in again I want to ask again
    A = questdlg('Would you like to retrain or test the network?', ...
        'Artificial Neural Network', 'Retrain', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');

    if strcmp (A, 'Retrain') do the first step as it is chosen the Train bit

    elseif strcmp(button,'Test') ...

    elseif strcmp(button,'Exit') ...

end
```

So how can I redirect my if statement to do the Train bit if the user chooses Retrain?

Comment: Do you know about the while-loop?

Comment: yes.. but i have never used it

Comment: if the user chooses Train then it will train the data using ANN and then save the data.. I just want to ask the use if he wants to retrain or to move to a next step.. if he wants to retrain it then the procedure will be the same as the train but with different results

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like this.

```
button = questdlg('Would you like to train or test the network?', ...
'Artificial Neural Network', 'Train', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');

% Loop until the user selects exit 
while ~strcmp(button,'Exit')

    % Button can be one of Exit, Test, Train or Retrain.
    % We know it's not Exit at this stage because we stop looping when Exit is selected.

    if strcmp(button,'Test')
        disp('Test');
    else
        % Must be either Train or Retrain
        disp('Training');
    end

    % We've done testing or training.  Ask the user if they want to repeat
    button = questdlg('Would you like to retrain or test the network?', ...
        'Artificial Neural Network', 'Retrain', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');\

end  % End of while statement.  Execution will unconditionally jump back to while.
```

Edit :  As Lucius points out, you could also do this with a switch statement which makes the choices slightly clearer.

```
button = questdlg('Would you like to train or test the network?', ...
'Artificial Neural Network', 'Train', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');

while ~strcmp(button,'Exit')

    switch button
        case 'Test'
            disp('Test');
        case {'Train','Retrain'}
            disp('Training');
    end

    button = questdlg('Would you like to retrain or test the network?', ...
        'Artificial Neural Network', 'Retrain', 'Test', 'Exit', 'Exit');
end
```

Comment: I really haven't undestood what u ve done there.. can u explain it a bit more pls?

Comment: :) too slow ;)... Just one thing to add: i would have used switch, but in this case the if does the job...

Comment: yes they do..:) when u say disp ('test') u mean that there will be my code? So i don't have to write disp('test')?

Comment: Yes, disp('Test') is just a placeholder for your code.  You'll probably want to put your testing & training code into separate functions (http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and just call the appropriate function instead of disp('...').

Comment: ok..and if the user selects Exit then the program will close or is there a code for the exit bit?

Comment: but im having a problem. when i run it and I choose Train it runs without stopping. I want as soon as the train is completed to stop and ask if u like to retrain it

Comment: If the user selects Exit the program will continue execution just after the end statement.  In my example code there is nothing after the end statement so the program execution will stop but you could add more code there is you want something to happen before exiting.

Comment: ok.. but how come and it repeats itself and not stop when the train is ended?

Comment: The code I have posted will always ask what the user wants to do until they select to exit. I don't know what your training code does.  If training is itself a loop of some sort you'll need to have a way of exiting that loop.  I think your original has now been answered.  Maybe you need to ask a new question related to your actual training code.